# Accessing data from the root of a json object JSRender

Tags: json, jsrender

I am currently creating a report using JSReport. I am now stuck in a scenario wherein I need to access data from inside the for loop. Here is a sample of the json

```
{
    "report_date": "",
    "account": "",
    "account_number": "",
    "data_retention": "",
    "data_purged": "",
    "sms_camp_del": "",
    "numbers_purged": "",
    "message_del": "",
    "reports": [{
        "count": 1,
        "campaign_name": "",
        "date": "",
        "start_time": "",
        "messages": "",
        "numbers": ""
    ...
```

And I already have this code

```
{{for reports}}
    ...
{{/for}}
```

and from the inside of the for loop I want to access the `report_date` and the `account` by using `{{:report_date}}` and `{{:account}}`, but the problem is that I cannot seem to output their respective values. How could I possibly access everything outside of the `reports`? Thank you in advance

Comment: I already found a way to access the needed data. <br>
Here's the code: <br>
`{{for reports ~rd=report_date ~ac=account}}...{{/for}}` and accessed by using `{{:~rd}}` and `{{:~ac}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use contextual parameters:

```
{{for reports ~rd=report_date ~ac=account}}...{{/for}}
```

and access using `{{:~rd}}` and `{{:~ac}}`

Another way is to use `{{:~root.report_date}}` and `{{:~root.account}}`.

See [Accessing parent data](http://www.jsviews.com/#parentdata) and [Accessing root data: the built-in '~root' contextual parameter](http://www.jsviews.com/#contextualparams@root).